# Novel about a guy with an implant that let him listen to other people's subvocalizations

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for a science fiction novel about a guy that had an implant behind his ear that enabled him to listen to others subvocalizing. I think the implant was named Diamanté. As I recall, I read it in the late 60’s, early 70’s.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You don't happen to remember the cover art, do you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

["Delay in Transit"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56270), a 1952 novelette by [F. L. Wallace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F._L._Wallace), available at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/50998). It was also the answer to the questions [Story about a neural computer personality implanted and communicated to using subvocalization](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186262/story-about-a-neural-computer-personality-implanted-and-communicated-to-using-su) and [Anyone remember a Golden Era pulp mag short story about a sentient(?) implantable computer named Manche?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/anyone-remember-a-golden-era-pulp-mag-short-story-about-a-sentient-implantabl). You may have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?56270).

The device is called Dimanche:

> Damn the man who was following him! It would be easy enough to elude him in a normal city. On Godolph, nothing was normal. In an hour the streets would be brightly lighted—for native eyes. A human would consider it dim.
>
> "Why did he choose me?" asked Cassal plaintively. "There must be something he hopes to gain."
>
> **"I'm working on it," said Dimanche. "But remember, I have limitations. At short distances I can scan nervous systems, collect and interpret physiological data. I can't read minds. The best I can do is report what a person says or subvocalizes.** If you're really interested in finding out why he wants to kill you, I suggest you turn the problem over to the godawful police."
>
> "Godolph, not godawful," corrected Cassal absently.
>
> That was advice he couldn't follow, good as it seemed. He could give the police no evidence save through Dimanche. There were various reasons, many of them involving the law, for leaving **the device called Dimanche** out of it. The police would act if they found a body. His own, say, floating face-down on some quiet street. That didn't seem the proper approach, either.

Part of the implant is behind the man's ear:

> For convenience of installation in the body, **Dimanche was packaged in two units. The larger package was usually surgeried into the abdomen. The small one, containing the speaker, was attached to the skull just behind the ear.** It worked by bone conduction, allowing silent communication between operator and instrument. A real convenience.